# Is it possible to add node automatically when hadoop program is on running application

Tags: hadoop

I'm beginner programmer and hadoop learner.
I'm testing hadoop full distribute mode using 5 PC(has Dual-core cpu and ram 2G)
 before starting maptask and hdfs, I knew that I must configure file(etc/hosts on Ip, hostname and hadoop folder/conf/masters,slaves file) so I finished configured that file

and when debating on seminar in my company, my boss and chief insisted that even if hadoop application running state, if hadoop need more node or cluster, automatically, hadoop will add more node
 Is it possible? When I studied about hadoop clusturing, Many hadoop books and community site insisted that after configuration and running application, We can't add more node or cluster.
 But My boss said to me that Amazon said adding node on running application is possible.
 Is really true? 
 hadoop master users on stack overflow community, Please tell me detail about the truth.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it indeed is possible.

[Here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#I_have_a_new_node_I_want_to_add_to_a_running_Hadoop_cluster.3B_how_do_I_start_services_on_just_one_node.3F) is the explanation in hadoop's wiki.

Also Amazon's EMR enables one to add 100s of nodes on-the-fly in an alreadt running cluster and as soon as the machines are up they are delegated tasks(unstarted mapper and/or reducer tasks) by the master.

So, yes, it is very much possible and is in use and not just in theory.

Comment: hmm
so,on only amazon EMR ,could I add node when hadoop is running state?
If I don't use amazon EMR, only using ubuntu 12.04, download hadoop and ssh and so on, adding node on running state is impossible ?
Master Amar Plz, help me

Comment: Did you look here: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#I_have_a_new_node_I_want_to_add_to_a_running_Hadoop_cluster.3B_how_do_I_start_services_on_just_one_node.3F